# adding data to firestore on user input

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Hi im trying to add data to firestore as shown below, but its saying that "undefined is not an object (evaluating "this.state"), i'm taking user email and name etc in by a text input box, why is this failing?

thank you!

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { AuthContext } from '../navigations/AuthProvider'
import {Alert} from 'react-native';
export default class Register extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerShown: false
    };

 
 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          name: "",
          email: "",
          password: "",
          errorMessage: ""
        };
 
       
    }
 
    handleSignUp = () => {
        try {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(function(user){
            const user2 = firebase.auth().currentUser;
           
            firebase.firestore().collection('users').add({
                email: user2.email,
                name: user2.displayName
              
              })
        
        
            });
          } catch (err) {
            Alert.alert('There is something wrong!', err.message);
          }
        }

    render () {
    
        return (
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar style="auto"/>
                    
                    <View style={styles.image_view}>  
                        <Image 
                        source={require("../assets/images/dcuhublogo_higherres.png")}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        resizeMode="center"
                        style={styles.image_style}>
                        </Image>
                    </View> 

                    <View style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        marginTop: -50,
                        marginBottom: 50
                    }}>
                        <Text style={{
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            fontSize: 17,
                            color: '#696868'
                        }}>{'Welcome to DCU Hub! \nSign up to get started.'} </Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                        {this.state.errorMessage && <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
                    </View>

                   < View style={styles.top_placeholder}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.placeholder_text}
                            placeholder="FULL NAME" autoCapitalize="none" onChangeText={name => this.setState({name})}
                            value={this.state.name}
                            ></TextInput>
                    </View>

                    

                    <View style={styles.placeholder_style}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.placeholder_text}
                            placeholder="DCU EMAIL" autoCapitalize="none" onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
                            value={this.state.email}
                            ></TextInput>
                    </View>

                                        
                    <View style={styles.placeholder_style}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.placeholder_text}
                            secureTextEntry={true}  // SECURE PASSWORD ie hides the texts
                            placeholder="PASSWORD" secureTextEntry autoCapitalize="none" onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            ></TextInput>
                    </View>

                    {/* THIS ALSO USES FIREBASE AUTHENTICATION
                        ONCED SIGNED UP, IT SHOULD TAKE THE USER TO THE
                        CREATE PROFILE SECTION/SCREEN */}
                    <View>
                        <Button2 text='SIGN UP' onPress={this.handleSignUp}/>
                    </View>


                    <View style={styles.to_signin}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}> Already have an account? </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                        <Text style={{color: "#d40059", fontSize: 18}}>Sign In</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
            
            </View>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

I've even tried to use a constructor,

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          name: "",
          email: "",
          password: "",
          errorMessage: ""
        };
 
       
    }
```

and this also fails, what am I doing wrong?

thanks so much!

Comment: You'll need to show the enclosing context, here - is this part of a Component Object?  A Functional Component?  We have no way to see what those fragments *intend* to do...

Comment: Hii, so basically I want to add the users name after they type it into a text input, I want to pass this into the firestore collection by using this.state.name, but whenever I do it , it fails and I'm not sure why. i'm new to javascript and react native. The email is showing up in the firestore database but  its showing as "name: null". I'm just trying to figure out how to add the user data to the firestore so I can use it for creating a user profile etc. Thank you! :)

Comment: You need to put this code in a class for it to work

Comment: @suddjian hi yes sorry it is in a class I didn't copy the class part

Comment: How are you updating the state when there is input? Can we see your render function?

Comment: @suddjian hii i updated it with my render function thank you:)

Comment: Hm, I have only done browser react not react native, but that looks correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: I suggest adding log messages to each step in the process to see if you can find out at what part of the react lifecycle it's getting messed up.